I'm struggling with creating a controller_manager within ros2_control
I'm using Python within the humble distro to control an omnidirectional robot in Gazebo fortress. I'm repeatedly receiving the following info messages

[spawner-6] [WARN] [1732275289.321053240] [joint_broad]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1732275289.321473749] [joint_broad]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...

This is my yaml file to configure the controllers.
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 50  # Hz, adjust as necessary

joint_state_broadcaster:
  type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

velocity_control:
  type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController

velocity_control:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - Left_wheel_joint
      - Right_wheel_joint
      - Rear_wheel_joint
    interface_name: velocity

This is my ros2_control section in my URDF folder.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    
  <xacro:macro name="omnibot_ros2_control">
    <xacro:arg name="name" default="Omnibot" />
    <ros2_control name="Omnibot" type="system">
      <hardware>
        <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSimSystem</plugin>
      </hardware>

      <joint name="Left_wheel_joint">
        <command_interface name="velocity">
          <param name="min">-10.0</param>
          <param name="max">10.0</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
      <joint name="Right_wheel_joint">
        <command_interface name="velocity">
          <param name="min">-10.0</param>
          <param name="max">10.0</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
      <joint name="Rear_wheel_joint">
        <command_interface name="velocity">
          <param name="min">-10.0</param>
          <param name="max">10.0</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
    </ros2_control>

  </xacro:macro>
    
</robot>

This is my launch file where it shows the ros2_control nodes being created
robot_controllers = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            FindPackageShare(package_name),
            "config",
            "omni_ctrllers.yaml",
        ]
    )

# control_node = Node(
#                 package="controller_manager",
#                 executable="ros2_control_node",
#                 name='controller_manager',
#                 parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time, 'use_ros2_control': use_ros2_control},robot_controllers],
#                 output="screen",
#             )
    
# Create a robot_state_publisher node
node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description_config, 'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}]
    ) 
    
joint_broad_spawner = TimerAction(
        period=11.0,  # Delay in seconds
        actions=[
            Node(
                package="controller_manager",
                executable="spawner",
                name='joint_broad',
                arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
            )
        ],
    )
omnibot_ctrl_spawner = TimerAction(
        period=11.0,  # Delay in seconds
        actions=[
            Node(
                package="controller_manager",
                executable="spawner",
                name='vel_control',
                arguments=["velocity_control", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
            )
        ],
    )
    
# Launch them all!
return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='false',
            description='Use sim time if true'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_ros2_control',
            default_value='true',
            description='Use ros2_control if true'),
    
        node_robot_state_publisher,
        world_arg,
        gazebo,
        spawn_entity,
        ros_gz_bridge,
      #  control_node,
        omnibot_ctrl_spawner,  
        joint_broad_spawner      
    ])

I'm willing to provide further details, if asked. I'm new to this, but I'm open to criticism.



/
0.01
$(find omni_three_bot)/config/omni_ctrllers.yaml

             Is this the right plugin to add to fortress to access the yamls? If not, I need the alternative plugin.
gazebo_ros2_control is for the gazebo classic simulator (the numbered ones).
For gazebo fortress and humble, you need ign_ros2_control

Great! With that out of the way, what about my controller_manager based on the executable 'ros2_control_node', which is just not starting? If you need more information or clarity, do let me know.

Have a look at the demos provided with the plugin. There is no need to launch a ros2_control_node.

You are absolutely right. I didn't need to. It's working right now btw.

Great! If so, please mark the question as answered.
